# Django - Moving database from development to production servers

Tags: mysql, django

I am working on a Django project with a MySQL backend. I'm curious about the best way to update a production server's database to reflect the changes made on the development server's database?

When I develop now, I make some changes to a `models.py` file, then to a `schemamigration` using [South](http://south.aeracode.org/). Sometimes I do several migrations across several apps within the main project folder before it's ready for the production database. This means that there are several migration files in the `app/migrations/` folder created by South.

So on the production server, how does one update the database to reflect all the changes made in development, without having any data loss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to creation migrations. South is probably most people's go to app in the Django world

http://south.aeracode.org/

Comment: I am using South, I mentioned it in my question. I'm not sure I understand what you're saying.

Comment: once your migration files are in place just run `./manage.py migrate` you don't lose any data stored in the table.

Comment: Won't that be a problem if on the development server, I've run `./manage migrate` several times due to multiple DB changes but, running `./manage.py migrate` on the production server only picks up the latest migration, not all the migrations that happened along the way? I guess I'm worried about missing migrations in between the first and last migration that I do on the dev server.

Comment: as long as all your migration files are in place it should pick them all up.

Comment: oh... wow, ok, and for sure they all go to the production server. Great thanks.

Comment: if they don't.. you can also apply a migration per file if needed.. It's listed in the docs. So worse case just apply each migration file but it should pick them all up